# How to open a Boxcryptor file from emacs running inside termux on Android

Tags: android

I'm using Boxcryptor to encrypt my files in Dropbox. I use termux to run emacs on my Android phone. I'm having trouble opening the Boxcryptor files in emacs because I don't know where to look for the file. With Dropbox I can find the file in storage/shared/Android/data/com.dropbox... etc. But it doesn't seem to be the same with Boxcryptor.

My current workaround is:

1. Download the file from Boxcryptor locally.
2. Open this file in emacs, make changes, save.
3. Upload the file to Boxcryptor again, overwriting the old file with the same name.

I'm wondering if there is perhaps a more elegant solution that doesn't require me manually overwriting the file every time I make a change. Boxcryptor states on their website that they integrate with Android's Storage Access Framework (https://www.boxcryptor.com/en/help/work-with-files/android/), but I'm not sure how to make that work with Termux in this situation.